# please help me how can i solve this

Tags: json, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

|
Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
> Searched Location:
> C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\todo_app\android\app\src\debug\google-services.json
> C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\todo_app\android\app\src\google-services.json
> C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\todo_app\android\app\google-services.json

Answer (score -1):

if you are using firebase in your project make sure to add `google-services.json` file in directory  `YourAPP/app/` and then clean and rebuild the project

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have a `google-services.json` file inside the folder `android/app`